# Changing the string in an input form while the user typing

Tags: javascript, input

I want to change the text in an input form to "*" as the user is typing. I have figured out how to change the text to asterisks and it shows in the console as asterisks but I can't get to change the text while the user is typing.
Here is my code:

```
const cardNumber = document.getElementById("input");
const reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");
cardNumber.addEventListener("keyup", function changeChar(){
    if(cardNumber.value.length <= 12){
        for(i=0; i<cardNumber.value.length; i++){
            const newValue = cardNumber.value[i].replace(reg, "*");//Replaces the number with an asterisk
            console.log(newValue);//Outputs as asterisks on the console
            cardNumber.value[i].innerHTML = newValue;//This doesn't seem to do the trick
        }

    }
});
```

I tried changing the value of the text with .value and .innerHTML method but it didn't work out.
I expect the text to change to asterisks as the user is typing.

Comment: Why not just use <input type="password"

Comment: I know about that method. It's actually a challenge and it specifies to change to asterisks.

Comment: `cardNumber.value[i]` is a character in a string. It doesn't have a `.innerHTML` attribute.

Comment: Once you change the value to asterisks, you can't know what the user was originally typing unless you also store it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this much more complicated than necessary.

Just get the length of the input, then create a string of `*` with the same length and assign that to the input value.

```js
cardNumber.addEventListener("keyup", function changeChar() {
  const asterisks = "************";
  if (cardNumber.value.length <= asterisks.length) {
    let newNumber = asterisks.substring(0, cardNumber.value.length);
    cardNumber.value = newNumber;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="cardNumber">
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, your own code is easier to understand and works just fine but I'm still confused as to why .value didn't work for me.

Comment: And I couldn't upvote because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I just found out why .value didn't work for me. Strings are immutable. Creating a new string and replacing the original string l(like you did) would have worked.

Comment: Even if strings were mutable, `.replace()` doesn't operate in place.

Comment: As I said above, your code deosn't work because `.innerHTML` is a property of elements, not strings.

Comment: Thanks. I used `.value` initially too as I said before and it didn't work with it.